# If position is position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my code in Unity, I've been trying to see if the rb's position is equal to cameraPos position but it doesn't work(nothing happends)

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
Vector2 cameraPos;

void Start ()
{
    cameraPos = new Vector2(0f, -3f);
}

if (rb.position == cameraPos)
    {            
        print("Continue");
    }
```

Comment: What does `rb`hold? Is the `position` approximately or exactly equal to `cameraPos`? You should be able to answer all this just by debugging this code.

Comment: What is not working?

If it is it failing to build (assuming the snippet you provided is copy-pasted), your if-statement must be declared within the scope of a function.


If you are simply not seeing the result you want to see in game, ensure the positions match exactly. If they are not, it is potentially an issue of frame-based movement (movement is not continuous in games; it is discrete). If that is the case, use snapping (set the positions to be precise) or use a proximity-based system (if the two are less than x units away from each other, than y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that two positions might never be exactly equal especially if using `RigidBody` without a `PlayerController`  because movements might actually "jump" between to frames.

The [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) operator you are currently using actually uses approximation but only to an accuracy of `1e-5` (`0.00001`) of the float values. This can lead to a little misunderstanding but it only means that e.g. `(0.99999, 0.99999, 0.99999) == (1,1,1)`. Anything more appart won't match.

You should rather use an approximation instead e.g. using [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) for checking if the objects are less then X meters appart where you can make X now greater or also smaller than 1e-5. In this example it should match if the objects are closer than 10cm:

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
Vector2 cameraPos;

// Set the threshold in meters
public float Threshold = 0.1f;

void Start ()
{
    cameraPos = new Vector2(0f, -3f);
}

if (Vector3.Distance(rb.position, cameraPos) <= Threshold)
{            
    print("Continue");
}
```

Depending on your needs you can than adjust the `Threshold` to be wider or more exact.

---

Alternatively you could as well use [Collisions / `Rigidbody.OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.OnCollisionEnter.html?_ga=2.123407757.764756647.1539068940-2141040499.1490886544) for tracking if certain objects are "close enough" / touching each other. Advantage of this approach is that you don't only know if the positions are close but also with which velocity both objects met.